# Angular: Setting the browser title according to active components

Tags: angular-2+

In an angular application I would like to set the browser title to something that is helpful. (Helpful means that the user gets a meaningful history and can identify tabs easily). Setting the title should be as automatic as possible. That means:

- If the route changes and the component that becomes active has title, then it should be used
- If the route changes and the component that becomes active has no title a default title should be used
- Dynamic titles should be allowed, so e.g. in the hero-app I might want to display the name of the hero currently displayed in the title
- The title must allow localization

Angular does have a the `Title`-Service to set the title, but it is setter-based, so I'd have to make sure that each and every route/component sets a title or every component that sets a tile needs to unset it in `ngOnDestroy`. That is already quite cumbersome and then there are situations where this won't work at all, because multiple components might override each other.

I could not find an existing solution, so I created my own. It looks like this:

1. I create my own `TitleService` which wraps angular's service:

   ```js
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { debounceTime, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
   import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import { BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';


   @Injectable({
       providedIn: 'root'
   })
   export class TitleService {
       private titleSegments = new BehaviorSubject<Observable<string>[]>([of('My App')]);

       constructor(private delegate: Title) {
           this.titleSegments
               .pipe(
                   switchMap((values: Observable<string>[]) => combineLatest(values)),
                   debounceTime(100) // Prevents "flickering", if during loading the title changes a lot
               )
               .subscribe(segments => this.delegate.setTitle(segments.join(' < ')));
       }

       addTitleSegment(segment: Observable<string>) {
           this.titleSegments.next([segment, ...this.titleSegments.value]);
       }

       popTitleSegment() {
           this.titleSegments.next(this.titleSegments.value.slice(1));
       }
   }
   ```
2. I create a directive and a component to interact with mit `TitleService`. Directive:

   ```js
   import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
   import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
   import { TitleService } from '../core/title.service';

   @Directive({
       selector: '[appPageTitle]'
   })
   export class PageTitleDirective implements OnDestroy {
       private title$ = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);

       constructor(private titleService: TitleService, el: ElementRef) {
           this.title$.subscribe(title => el.nativeElement.innerText = title);
           titleService.addTitleSegment(this.title$);
       }

       @Input()
       set appPageTitle(title: string) {
           this.title$.next(title);
       }

       ngOnDestroy(): void {
           this.titleService.popTitleSegment();
       }
   }
   ```

   Component:

   ```js
       import { Component, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
   import { TitleService } from '../core/title.service';
   import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

   @Component({
       selector: 'app-page-title',
       template: '',
   })
   export class PageTitleComponent implements OnDestroy {
       private title$ = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);

       constructor(private titleService: TitleService) {
           titleService.addTitleSegment(this.title$);
       }

       @Input()
       set title(title: string) {
           this.title$.next(title);
       }

       ngOnDestroy(): void {
           this.titleService.popTitleSegment();
       }
   }
   ```

   The component and the directive are very similar. I use the directive most of the time, so I can use heading and title in one go, but in case there is no heading I use the directive, which has no effect on the UI.

Now I can simply use the directive/component in my HTML. E.g. like this:

root.html:

```html
<h1 appPageTitle="Heroes"></h1>
<app-edit-hero></app-edit-hero>
```

edit.html:

```html
<h1 [appPageTitle]="'edit' + hero.name"></h1>
...
```

And in this case I get (if `hero.name === 'My Hero'`):

> edit My Hero < Heroes < MY APP

As browser title, which looks great. Also it is very easy to manage, since this happens mostly automatically, whenever routes change or the data I would like changes.

Questions:

- Are there any hidden pitfalls? E.g. I depend on the correct order of construction and destruction of components when navigating. Are there any cases where this might be a problem?
- Is this OK with standard angular coding best practices?
- Is there anything from the usability/accessibility perspective that might be a problem?
- Any general suggestions of improvement?
- Are there other existing approaches, that I have missed during my research?